# Why is my character collision working for moving to the right, but not to the left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to create a boundary for my level in Unity 3d, and I do not want my character to be able to move past a certain value on the x-axis. It works for the right side, I can move right and my character doesn't go past `LevelBounds.rightSide`. However, for the left side, once I hit `LevelBounds.leftSide`, my character gets stuck and I can no longer move anymore. I am also noticing that the x position actually exceeds the `LevelBounds.leftSide`. Here is my `update()` function:

```
 void Update()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x > LevelBounds.leftSide)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);
    }
    if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x > LevelBounds.rightSide)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);
    }
    player.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

Comment: Should it be: `this.gameObject.transform.position.x < LevelBounds.leftSide` ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using colliders in Unity instead of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using an input axis that ranges from -1 to 1. You should either use:

```
Math.Abs(horizontalInput);
```

or:

```
Vector3.right
```

on both time.